# Exporting Parse.com data to JSON file from swift code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to export the Parse.com data to a JSON file from the code instead of having to click the button on the website? Thanks!

Comment: Probably. What have you checked out so far?

Comment: Why are you asking (effectively) the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250405/automatically-exporting-parse-data

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I could figure something out for my first post if I knew how to do this.